# Disable page scroll until page loads - JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have built a parallax scrolling intro for a clients website - the site contains many high res images - so I have created a quick loader which blanks out the screen with a full screen high z-index div and then uses the setTimeout method to fade in the page 4 seconds after document ready (not sure if this is the best way to do this but it works in every test I've tried).

I would like to disable the scroll to prevent users scrolling through the animation before it appears -can anyone recommend a good cross-browser method to do this?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to fade in when all images are loaded, you can try this

```
var images = $('img');
var images_nbr = images.length;

images.load(function() {
    images_nbr--;

    if (images_nbr == 0) {
        $('body').css('overflow','auto');
        $('...').fadeIn();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
#mydiv {
    overflow:hidden 
}
```

in your parent div in CSS. Then, in your document, add this...

```
$('#mydiv').css('overflow', 'auto');
```

...in the function that fades in your content.

Thus, on load the page will be unscrollable, but when you fade in, the overflow property will be overwritten and allow the content to scroll.

Answer (score 0):

```
.scrolldiv{
overflow:hidden;
}

$(window).load(function(){
   $(".scrolldiv").css("overflow","auto");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like,
initially add the below css on body

```
body {overflow:hidden;}
```

and after your setInterval function complete execution (whatever your loading function) just remove the style from body, like

```
$('body').css('overflow','auto');
```